# Google custom search missing information compared to google.com

Tags: google-custom-search

I have created a programmable search engine to use inside Google custom search site restricted API but I don't see some information that appears when I search the exact same query. Can I change something to get it?

[image: picture-1]

first picture of programmable search engine and second from google.com

[image: picture 2]

any lead is most appreciated. I'm missing location string.